# Why does the node.js in VS code work only after several attempts

Tags: javascript, node.js

the node.js in VS code work only after several attempts
even after try 'run' many times.

````
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(new Date());
}).listen(5500);```

it shows the error 
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5500
even though 5500 is completely empty

```------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------```
````

Comment: That crashes for me. _"The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Date"_: which is telling you that you need to most likely stringify the data before you send it.

Comment: @Andy no even after i use a string it does not work

Answer (score 0):

As it says: `EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5500`

That means that some service or program somewhere is currently using port 5500. That could be anything, but most likely a previous run of your program that wasn't properly cleaned up.

Graceful shutdown is always preferred, so that you don't make yourself run into these issues:

```
const server = http.createServer({ /*[...]*/ });

const shutdownProcedure = () => {
  // Do stuff before shutdown
  server.close();
};

process.on("SIGINT", shutdownProcedure);
process.on("SIGTERM", shutdownProcedure);
process.on("SIGHUP", shutdownProcedure);

server.listen(5500);
```

Comment: i tried many ports like 4503, 6000 but none works

Comment: Could you try any of the following commands and see if you see ports you've tried: `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`, `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`, `sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

Comment: sudo not defined

Comment: On windows you can use `netstat -aon | findstr /c:"LISTEN"`